# Reduce app's memory usage in PhoneGap

Tags: android, html, cordova, memory

I have created app in PhoneGap which is just a simple digital clock written in HTML5 and JavaScript. The app eats ~12MB in v2.3 and ~18MB memory in v4.0+. Considering there is very little animation, how can I reduce the app's memory usage. Also how to kill app whenever minimized to free up the resources. App doesn't take much time to load.

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solve by several techniques for example you can remove garbage value by using

```
   System.gc();
```

use above statement to appropriate place in you code.

Even you can compress and re size the images that are being used in app.

Answer (score 0):

Compress your javascript before you build any phoneGap application.It will reduce huge amount of code and makes your application performance faster.Here is the link through which you can compress your javascript.I have faced similar kind of issues and this solution worked for me.
[Javascript Compressor](http://javascriptcompressor.com/)